# Google Places API does support

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

do Autocomplete service in the Google Places API does support the simultaneous inclusion of both countries and cities in the same Autocomplete instance.

var options = {
types: ['(cities)','country']};

please let me know is we can..?

Comment: [Here's the documentation for "types"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#types).

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/supported_types#table3):

> **Table 3: Type collections supported in Place Autocomplete requests**
> Use the Place type values in Table 3, or the values in Table 1 and Table 2, as part of a Place Autocomplete request to restrict the results to a specific type.
> ***Only a single type from Table 3 is allowed in the request. If you do specify a value from Table 3, you cannot specify a value from Table 1 or Table 2.*** (emphasis added)
> The supported types are:
>
> - **geocode**
> - **address**
> - **establishment**
> - **(regions)** type collection
> - **(cities)** type collection

Therefore  `types: ['(cities)','country']` is not allowed, as only a single value from Table 3 is allowed.